# Getting total number of intervals using joda time

Tags: java, jsp, date, jodatime

I have this code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.text.*,org.joda.time.*"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
  try {
      int freq=30;  //30 minutes
      String d1=request.getParameter("date");
      String d2=d1;
      String t1=request.getParameter("starttime");
      String t2=request.getParameter("endtime");
      String date1 = d1;
      String time1 = t1;
      String date2 = d2;
      String time2 = t2;
      String format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a";
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
      Date dateObj1 = sdf.parse(date1 + " " + time1);
      Date dateObj2 = sdf.parse(date2 + " " + time2);
      DateTime dateObj12 = new DateTime(dateObj1);
      DateTime dateObj22 = new DateTime(dateObj2);
      long diff = dateObj2.getTime() - dateObj1.getTime();
      double diffInHours = diff / ((double) 1000 * 60 * 60);
      //out.println(diffInHours+" hours"+ "<br>");
      final Period period = new Period(dateObj12, dateObj22);
      //out.print(period.getDays() + " days, ");
      out.print(period.getHours() + " hours, ");
      out.print(period.getMinutes() + " minutes, ");
      //out.print(period.getSeconds() + " seconds.");
  } 
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives me the hours difference.
Next I want to get the number of intervals.
As above you can see I have used `freq=30;` which is the interval I want.
So between a certain time for example 11.30 am to 5.00 pm with interval period of 30 minutes I should get 11 intervals.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joda time has great support for these kind of things. This should do it for you:

```
int minutesBetween = Minutes.minutesBetween(dateObj12, dateObj22).getMinutes();
int numberOfIntervals = minutesBetween / freq;
```

Javadoc: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html